# Discord Bot Python Channel Creati

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am pretty new at developing and I want to make a command in python for discord bot for making new channels (not one channel more or something like loop), how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as nobody will code all of this for you nor is StackOverflow a "*Implement this for me*" platform.

Answer (score 0):

[image: image1]

```
@commands.command()
async def make_channel(self,ctx, *, channelname:str):
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(channelname)
    await ctx.send(f"{channelname} created")
```